# How to join two difrent lines in same line in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, text-processing

From Nagios I downloaded its html file by using the command `wget`, then I converted that html file to text file using following command:

```
html2text -width 180 file.html >1.txt
```

Alert Summary Report

```
                                             Most Recent Alerts                   
                                        08-01-2018 06:11:52 to 08-10-2018 
                                              Duration: 7d 0h 0m 0s
                                                                                    Report Options Summary:

                                                                        Alert Types: Host & Service Alerts
                                                                                State Types: Hard States
                                                                                  Host States: Up, Down, Unreachable
                                                                                 Service States:    Warning, Unknown, Critical

                                   Displaying all 4 matching alerts


                      DISK OK - free space:          CRITICAL
01-08-2018 07:05:05   Service Required     Critical  CPU:loadaverage 6.0%                    

01-08-2018 07:10:25   Service Alert        Critical  memoryUsage

                       DISK OK - free space: 
02-08-2018 01:05:2018  Service Alert       Warning   memoryUsage

                                                      CRITICAl:outstanding alert attention 
02-08-2018 02:05:2018  Service Alert        Critical  required
```

After then, I cut the first ten lines using the command:

```
awk 'NR > 10 { print }'1.txt > 2.txt
```

Here is the content of file 2.txt:

```
                      DISK OK - free space:          CRITICAL
01-08-2018 07:05:05   Service Required     Critical  CPU:loadaverage 6.0%                    

01-08-2018 07:10:25   Service Alert        Critical  memoryUsage

                       DISK OK - free space: 
02-08-2018 01:05:2018  Service Alert       Warning   memoryUsage

                                                      CRITICAl:outstanding alert attention 
02-08-2018 02:05:2018  Service Alert        Critical  required
```

I would like to merge two rows into a single row not for all the lines, but only for a particular output from the file b.txt.

Note: the text file contains N number of lines

**Expected output:**

```
01-08-2018 07:05:05   DISK OK - free space:Service Required  Critical    CRITICALservice requiredCPU:loadaverage 6.0%

01-08-2018 07:10:25   Service Alert                          Critical    memoryUsage

02-08-201801:05:2018  DISK OK - free space:Service Alert     Warning     memoryUsage

02-08-2018 02:05:2018 Service Alert                         Critical     CRITICAL:outstanding alert attention required
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post sample input of file1.txt too in your post and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 its just unwanted lines from nagios so that I cut those lines from 1.txt but actual input is 2.txt

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I added File 1.txt too please check

Comment: Can't you read nagios status in json or more parsable format? Wouldn't that help?

Comment: Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053365/how-to-merge-two-rows-in-a-same-row-from-a-text-file-in-linux-shell-script/52053765#52053765

Comment: @oliv I'm not getting exact output from that code. lines are not merged properly

Comment: I can't help feeling you would be better parsing this direct from the HTML where you could easily identify the types of each row that you want to join together, and name each field you want to tabulate. By the way `tail -c +10` will get you all but the first 10 lines.

Comment: @GemTaylor I feel convenient with awk

Comment: GUYS any idea still i'm facing the same issue

Comment: still I'm struggling suggestions needed

Comment: @ arunmoezhi is that possible to the above issue