# How to combine two different rows by using awk sed or shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a file file.txt. I have to merge two different rows into one.

**file.txt**

```
                  linux-
02-10-2018 11:50  is-a-opensource  user    file
02-10-2018 11:46  linux-userfile   user    file1
                                   user-1
02-10-2018 11:40  linux-userfile   user    file2
                  linux-           user-2
02-10-2018 11:30  linux-userfile   user    file3
```

**Expected output**

```
 02-10-2018 11:50  linux-is-a-opensource  user    file
 02-10-2018 11:46  linux-userfile         user    file1
 02-10-2018 11:40  linux-userfile         user1user    file2
 02-10-2018 11:30  linux-linux-userfile         user-2user    file3
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

I tried with the command below but that didn't do it.

```
  $ awk ' /^ +/{ gsub(/^ +/," ");a=a $0; next }{ $2=$2a;a=""}1' file.txt
```

I'm getting below error

```
  02-10-2018 11:50 linux- is-a-opensource user file
  02-10-2018 11:46 linux-userfile user file1
  02-10-2018 11:40 user-1 linux-userfile user file2
  02-10-2018 11:30 linux-           user-2 linux-userfile user file3
```

and I tried the below links for reference but still I'm getting the same error
[How to Merge 2 diffrent lines in linux by using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52671122/608639)

[How to merge two rows in a same row from a text file in linux shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053365/how-to-merge-two-rows-in-a-same-row-from-a-text-file-in-linux-shell-script)

Comment: Duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671122/how-to-merge-2-diffrent-lines-in-linux-by-using-awk)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Merge 2 diffrent lines in linux by using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52671122/608639)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two rows in a same row from a text file in linux shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053365/how-to-merge-two-rows-in-a-same-row-from-a-text-file-in-linux-shell-script). rajaviknesh's first question.

Comment: @Cyrus its diffrent scenario please check it

Comment: This is very complicated without "rules" on the input. What are the rules here? Are the columns always the same width? Clearly not, as column 2 of the input and output change. Does column 2 always contain a hyphen? But then column 3 also contains a hyphen. How do we distinguish between the columns? Can there apper something in column4 in the to-merge-line

Comment: @kvantour the column have diffrent size , in some places it doesn't contains hyphen, totally 5 columns which is like Expected output

Comment: So, is the file tab-delimitted? Or at least something, because how are we going to distinguish between columns 3 (linux-) and 4 (user-1)? Is the input-file always aligned?

Comment: @kvantour yes its tab-delimitted .

Comment: @kvantour the input file is always aligned .

Comment: A tab-delimitted file is useful if all columns are separated by a single tab. However, since you say they are aligned, it indicates that multiple tabs could be used to separate columns (eg. in the first line, the string "linux" probably already has two or three tabs in front of it, making it column 3 or 4. While user1 could be potentially in column-7. I present below an answer for space separated version, but i'll add a line to solve this tab-dillema

Comment: @User123 I agree that this could be used, but here `FIELDWIDTHS` might not be an option due to the tabs. Otherwise, a remarkably similar question.

Comment: @Cyrus I'm getting default input .I'm not getting the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is hard to determine which column the string belongs to, I make the following assumption:

- The columns are **perfectly aligned and space separated**

so the following [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script will assume:

- A line that does not start with a date will be merged into the **next** line
- The width of the columns will be determined by the column-width of **next** line

**note:** if your file is aligned with blanks (a combination of tabs and spaces), we cannot make use of the field separator "\t" to distinguish fields as the number of tabs will depend on the field width.

Here is the tested script:

```
# If you have a tab-aligned file, replace all tabs by the
# correct sequence of spaces. In this example, we assume a single
# tab is equivalent to 8 spaces. Adopt if needed
{ gsub(/\t/,"        ",$0) }

# If the line does not start with a combination of numbers and hyphens
# it is a line that needs to be merged into the next line.
# store it and move to the next line
($1 !~ /^[-0-9]+$/) { tomerge=$0; next }

# If we picked up a tomerge line, try to figure out the fields
# by looking into the current line and determining the field widths.
(tomerge != "")  {
      # extract fields
      n=1 
      for(i=1;i<NF;++i) {
         m=index($0,$(i+1))
         field[i]=substr(tomerge,n,m-n)
         sub(/^[[:blank:]]*/,"",field[i])  # remove leading blanks
         sub(/[[:blank:]]*$/,"",field[i])  # remove trailing blanks
         n=m
      }
      field[NF]=substr(tomerge,n)
      # perform merging
      for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) $i= field[i] $i
      # reset the tomerge value
      tomerge=""
}
# print the line
{ $1=$1;print $0 }
```

which outputs:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file.txt
02-10-2018 11:50 linux-is-a-opensource user file
02-10-2018 11:46 linux-userfile user file1
02-10-2018 11:40 linux-userfile user-1user file2
02-10-2018 11:30 linux-linux-userfile user-2user file3
```

If you want it aligned, you can pass it to `column -t` as

```
$ awk -f script.awk file.txt | column -t
```

Comment: its working & mind blowing I'm trying this for the past 2 weeks .Thanks a lot

Comment: I have one more issue with your script

Comment: @rajaviknesh and that is?

Comment: i'm facing a issue while merging the line 
what if suppose the field was down to particular line
I have no idea how to merge the down space/blank field to previous line

Comment: here I created a new scenario for more clarification, expecting your positive response

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398356/merging-and-aligning-the-line-in-linux