# merging and aligning the line in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a text file named as file1.txt .and its need to be aligned like below expected output .
Note:The input file file1.txt is TAB delemitted and its always aligned.

```
                      DISK OK - free space:          CRITICAL
01-08-2018 07:05:05   Service Required     Critical  CPU:loadaverage 6.0%                    

01-08-2018 07:10:25   Service Alert        Critical  memoryUsage
                                                     :critical alert
                       DISK OK - free space:
02-08-2018 01:05:20    Service Alert       Warning   memoryUsage
                                                     :1.0,2.0,5.0


                                                     CRITICAl:outstanding alert attention 
02-08-2018 02:05:20    Service Alert       Critical  required
```

Expected Output:

```
 01-08-2018 07:05:05    DISK OK - free space:Service Required Critical    CRITICALservice requiredCPU:loadaverage 6.0%

 01-08-2018 07:10:25    Service Alert                         Critical    memoryUsage:critical alert

 02-08-2018 01:05:20    DISK OK - free space:Service Alert    Warning     memoryUsage:1.0,2.0,3.0

 02-08-2018 02:05:20    Service Alert                         Critical     CRITICAL:outstanding alert attention required
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Please do add your efforts in your post what you have to solve the problem?

Comment: @kvantour now the question is corrected thanks for the finding

Comment: This has been asked several times. Have a look at the `column(1)` command [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47833). You want to use the tab literal `$'\t'` as the column separator.

Comment: @EliasToivanen its a diffrent scenario

Comment: @Kvantour hope you got the scenario expecting the positive reply

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to pull this off:

```
 awk -F"\t" '!$1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){line[i]=$i};next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf i<NF?"%s%s%s":"%s%s%s\n",line[i],$i,FS}}' yourfile
```

If you need the output all aligned like you have it here (not tab delimited, but more like fixed width) you can pipe to `column`

```
awk -F"\t" '!$1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){line[i]=$i}} $1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf i<NF?"%s%s%s":"%s%s%s\n",line[i],$i,FS}}' test.log | column -t -s $'\t'
```

Basically what this is doing is:

1. Splitting each line by tab `-F"\t"`
2. If the first column is empty, then collect each column for this line into an array by the column number as index and proceed to the next record`!$1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){line[i]=$i};next}`
3. If we are still processing the line (that first condition didn't trip) then go through each column `{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)`
4. and print out what's stored in the array, the contents of the column of the current line, the Field Separator (tab), and a line feed if this is the last column `{printf i<NF?"%s%s%s":"%s%s%s\n",line[i],$i,FS}}`

Example of this in use:

```
$ cat test.log
        DISK OK - free space:           CRITICAL
1/8/2018 7:05:05        Service Required        Critical        CPU:loadaverage 6%

1/8/2018 7:10:25        Service Alert   Critical        memoryUsage
                        :critical alert
        DISK OK - free space:
2/8/2018 1:05:20        Service Alert   Warning memoryUsage
                        :1.0,2.0,5.0


                        CRITICAl:outstanding alert attention
2/8/2018 2:05:20        Service Alert   Critical        required

$ awk -F"\t" '!$1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){line[i]=$i};next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf i<NF?"%s%s%s":"%s%s%s\n",line[i],$i,FS}}' test.log | column -t -s $'\t'
1/8/2018 7:05:05  DISK OK - free space:Service Required  Critical  CRITICALCPU:loadaverage 6%
1/8/2018 7:10:25  Service Alert                          Critical  memoryUsage
2/8/2018 1:05:20  DISK OK - free space:Service Alert     Warning   memoryUsage
2/8/2018 2:05:20  Service Alert                          Critical  CRITICAl:outstanding alert attentionrequired
```

Comment: I tried the above code but its not working .I'm getting same data